# search box click location not properly in css

Tags: html, css

I created search box using codepen,

Here is code:

```css
.search-box {
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 100;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #555;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: none;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: width .4s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.795, 0.000, 1.000);
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="text"]:focus:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  width: 700px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
  cursor: text;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  height: 127px;
  width: 53px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  float: right;
  background: url("http://s18.postimg.org/f4t3rukcl/icon.png")center center no-repeat;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .4s ease;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <form action="" autocomplete="on">
    <input id="search" name="search" class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="What're we looking for ?">
    <input id="search_submit" value="" type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w8xzr2n1/)

When i click on the icon, it doesn't work properly.. somewhere click on the icon, it works.

May i know, how to fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Remove padding value and check the same :)

Comment: anybody can help? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work proper i think. You should use jquery too.

[find demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/w8xzr2n1/12/)

```
$('#search_submit, .search-box').focus(function(){
  $('.search-box').addClass('search-width');
});
$('#search_submit, .search-box').blur(function(){
  $('.search-box').removeClass('search-width');
});
```

Comment: without jquery is possible? and your demo still something from my need,, thanks..

Comment: i need same like this http://codepen.io/CBeghin/pen/HeuiF/ .. only different is, i replaced search icon.thanks

Comment: ohh.. Only that.
[check changes in your fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/w8xzr2n1/6/)

[change in codepe code] (http://jsfiddle.net/w8xzr2n1/5/)

Comment: (jsfiddle.net/w8xzr2n1/5) is correct..but the text "what we looking for" and icon. have to need to some space right? thanks

Comment: only space for text.. not for underline.. you understood when see in codepen.. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78281/discussion-between-saina-and-locateganesh).

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of options to implement this function. Have you tried **button** height to `height:74px` ?

```css
.search-box {
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 100;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #555;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: none;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: width .4s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.795, 0.000, 1.000);
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="text"]:focus:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  width: 700px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
  cursor: text;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  height: 74px;
  width: 53px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  float: right;
  background: url("http://s18.postimg.org/f4t3rukcl/icon.png")center center no-repeat;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  cursor: pinter;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .4s ease;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <form action="" autocomplete="on">
    <input id="search" name="search" class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="What're we looking for ?">
    <input id="search_submit" value="" type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

It seems to work for me on FF
[image]

Comment: it doesn't work.. when click the icon again.. thanks

Comment: @Saina which browser are you using ?

Comment: @saina let me try for you in FF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78276/discussion-between-saina-and-muhammed-athimannil).

Answer (score 0):

Add this **css**

```
.search-box{top:28px}
```

if not try this

```
input[type="submit"] {height: 68px;}
```

Comment: ok.. but when click the icon again, it doesn't work right? .. if click again outside of icon it works.. thanks..

Comment: @saina i think u check in jsfiddle? since the result text z-index is more the search icon bottom of it.. its the reason. but if u face the issue after applying this css in your project let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
form {
    position: relative;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    z-index:9;
}
```

Comment: In the future, be sure to provide an explanation with your answer.